# Embedded fonts - Verification: Different tools give different answers

Tags: fonts, pdf, embedding

I want to produce a PDF file that has all fonts embedded. I prefer to avoid the detour of postscript/dvi and use pdflatex instead.
My PDF is basically a publication containing only OmniGraffle figures and Matplotlib plots. OmniGraffle does embed fonts in its output and I tweaked Matplotlib to do this too.

Now I have two PDFs:

- "v1": My old one. I thought it did not have all fonts embedded as this was indicated by Adobe Reader.
- "v2". The new pdf after making sure each figure itself (pdf/eps) has all fonts embedded.

What puzzles me is that the command line tool `pdffonts`from the `xpdf` packet shows that both documents have all fonts embedded. However, Adobe Reader shows that PDF "v1" has some fonts that are not marked as "embedded" or "embedded (subset)" and only "v2" has all fonts embedded. Which tool is right and what does it mean?

Output of `pdffonts` of file "v1":

```
name                                 type              emb sub uni object ID
------------------------------------ ----------------- --- --- --- ---------
YVQUYJ+NimbusSanL-Bold               Type 1            yes yes no       5  0
RFXWRS+NimbusSanL-Regu               Type 1            yes yes no       6  0
KSUZRI+NimbusRomNo9L-Medi            Type 1            yes yes no       7  0
AFESAY+CMR9                          Type 1            yes yes no       8  0
RGQDWF+CMBX9                         Type 1            yes yes no       9  0
WQHQIA+NimbusRomNo9L-Regu            Type 1            yes yes no      10  0
OKJZSU+CMBXTI10                      Type 1            yes yes no      11  0
FUQITS+CMSY9                         Type 1            yes yes no      12  0
GUDTZQ+CMTI9                         Type 1            yes yes no      13  0
WWZKWK+Helvetica-Bold                TrueType          yes yes no      20  0
WSJVMY+CMEX10                        Type 1            yes yes yes     23  0
ICHZZX+HelveticaNeue                 TrueType          yes yes no      24  0
WSJVMY+CMEX10                        Type 1            yes yes yes     26  0
WJYTBK+NimbusRomNo9L-ReguItal        Type 1            yes yes no      81  0
AZNHSE+CMMI9                         Type 1            yes yes no      82  0
VHIYAC+CMR6                          Type 1            yes yes no      83  0
DIUTNF+CMMI6                         Type 1            yes yes no      84  0
FLUOTV+CMSY6                         Type 1            yes yes no      85  0
RVPZIX+CMMI5                         Type 1            yes yes no      86  0
UVMOBZ+CMBX6                         Type 1            yes yes no      91  0
BitstreamVeraSans-Roman              Type 3            yes no  no      93  0
THPNLT+CMEX9                         Type 1            yes yes no     133  0
BitstreamVeraSans-Roman              Type 3            yes no  no     136  0
RSRDYI+wasy9                         Type 1            yes yes no     184  0
LOHQHD+Helvetica                     TrueType          yes yes no     195  0
HAQIGV+Helvetica-Bold                TrueType          yes yes no     196  0
Cmmi10                               Type 3            yes no  no     278  0
BitstreamVeraSans-Roman              Type 3            yes no  no     279  0
```

Output of `pdffonts` of file "v2":

```
name                                 type              emb sub uni object ID
------------------------------------ ----------------- --- --- --- ---------
YVQUYJ+NimbusSanL-Bold               Type 1            yes yes no       5  0
EDVTZM+NimbusSanL-Regu               Type 1            yes yes no       6  0
KSUZRI+NimbusRomNo9L-Medi            Type 1            yes yes no       7  0
AFESAY+CMR9                          Type 1            yes yes no       8  0
DWJEZG+CMCSC10                       Type 1            yes yes no       9  0
QJCAMK+CMBX9                         Type 1            yes yes no      10  0
GULYAI+NimbusRomNo9L-Regu            Type 1            yes yes no      11  0
YDOJNG+NimbusRomNo9L-ReguItal        Type 1            yes yes no      12  0
OKJZSU+CMBXTI10                      Type 1            yes yes no      13  0
BWVALK+CMSY9                         Type 1            yes yes no      14  0
CFSIIM+CMTI9                         Type 1            yes yes no      15  0
WWZKWK+Helvetica-Bold                TrueType          yes yes no      22  0
WSJVMY+CMEX10                        Type 1            yes yes yes     25  0
ICHZZX+HelveticaNeue                 TrueType          yes yes no      26  0
WSJVMY+CMEX10                        Type 1            yes yes yes     28  0
AJQTGA+CMMI9                         Type 1            yes yes no      83  0
VHIYAC+CMR6                          Type 1            yes yes no      84  0
DIUTNF+CMMI6                         Type 1            yes yes no      85  0
FLUOTV+CMSY6                         Type 1            yes yes no      86  0
RVPZIX+CMMI5                         Type 1            yes yes no      87  0
UVMOBZ+CMBX6                         Type 1            yes yes no      92  0
BitstreamVeraSans-Roman              CID TrueType      yes no  yes     94  0
THPNLT+CMEX9                         Type 1            yes yes no     110  0
BitstreamVeraSans-Roman              CID TrueType      yes no  yes    113  0
RSRDYI+wasy9                         Type 1            yes yes no     125  0
IXWXMR+MSAM10                        Type 1            yes yes no     126  0
VSGEIH+Helvetica                     TrueType          yes yes no     136  0
ZBYQCO+Helvetica-Bold                TrueType          yes yes no     137  0
BitstreamVeraSans-Roman              CID TrueType      yes no  yes    228  0
Cmmi10                               CID TrueType      yes no  yes    229  0
```

I am using pdffonts 3.03 and Adobe Reader 11.0.2 on Windows 7.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx).

Comment: Can you include a screenshot from Adobe Reader? Also make sure to use a recent version of `pdffonts`, i.e. one with a recent version of poppler.

Comment: A screenshot of what? The font dialog? It doesn't fit completely in a screenshot as the list of fonts needs scrolling.

Comment: Use `pdffonts -v` to get its current version (recent version is 0.20.4).

Comment: I did this: `pdffonts -v` yields `pdffonts version 3.03
Copyright 1996-2011 Glyph & Cog, LLC` (I am working on Windows)